# Java modulo operator and GCD

Tags: java, modulo, greatest-common-divisor, fractions

Why does this code give me an answer of 25?

```
public int findGcd() {
    int num = this.num;
    int den = this.den;

    while (den != 0) {
        int t = den;
        den = num % den;
        num = t;
    }

    return num;
}
```

This is the main method:

```
public class FractionTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Fraction f = new Fraction();
        f.num = 25;
        f.den = 100;
        f.findGcd();
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide me a complete process of how all the program goes or run?

Comment: Well, what answer were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting a 4 or 0 since 25/100 is 4 while 25%100 = 4 , sorry I am just really confused can anyone clear things up

Comment: 25/100 is 0, 25%100 is 25, 100/25 is 4 and 100%25 is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Because `gcd(25, 100) = 25` probably

Comment: As this is probably a follow up to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882618/simplifying-fractions-with-java): Indeed 25 is the GCD. Now to simplify the fraction divide both the numerator and denominator by 25 and you get 1/4 instead of 25/100. Which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is called the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: I know it's the Euclidean algorithm , I used the pseudocde there for my code, all I want is to have a complete explanation of how the program goes since I've been having a hard time with the modulo operator

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick calculation you can also do by debugging your program to see how it works...

http://gcd.awardspace.com/?num1=25&num2=100&OG=on&SC=on&RF=on&RC=on

The link shows you how the calculation is done, if you can't see it yet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop work like this

den!=0 100 != 0

inside loop

t = 25 (den)

0 = 25 % 100

num = 25 (t)

return 25 (num)

So the result is 25